# In vue can not change value of one variable when changing other

Tags: vue.js

when I input the value of 'count', want to change the value of 'countcolor' instantly.
I don't understand the binding of the value or is this need component to introduce?
What to do?

```
<div id="app-13"> 
            give a count to know the color (0,1 or anything)<br>
            <input type="text" name="" v-model="count" v-on:keyup.enter="cometh"><br> 
            <p>when the count is {{ count }}<br>
              color is <span>{{ countcolor }}</span>
            </p>
          </div>
```

and js is:

```
var app13 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-13',
  data: {
    count: 0,
    countcolor: 'green'
  },
  methods:{
        cometh: function(){
            
            if(this.count === 0){
                this.countcolor === 'green'
            }else if(this.count === 1){
                this.countcolor === 'red'
            }else{
                this.countcolor === 'blue'
            }
        }
    }
  
})
```

Comment: `===` *compares* two values, `=` *assigns* a value. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the computed property just as follows

```
var app13 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-13',
  data: {
    count: 0,
  },
  computed:{
        countcolor() {       
            if(this.count === 0){
                return 'green'
            }else if(this.count === 1){
                return 'red'
            }else{
                return 'blue'
            }
        }
    }
})
```

and then you can render it by

```
<div id="app-13"> 
            give a count to know the color (0,1 or anything)<br>
            <input type="text" name="" v-model="count"><br> 
            <p>when the count is {{ count }}<br>
              color is <span>{{ countcolor }}</span>
            </p>
          </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the 'else if' part is not working. Also the 'countcolor' is changing only once.

Comment: try defining the data as a function

Comment: data() {
return { count: 0, } }

Comment: got same result.

Comment: Please make sure you have removed the countcolor variable from the data() section

Comment: Can you please rewrite the whole code for me again?